# Quip API - Can I use the personal access token to access threads/create documents?

Tags: quip

I generated a personal access token for QUIP, but it only shows "invalid access token" whenever I run a call using postman. Can I use the personal token to do this? Or do I need another access token from the admin?

Comment: Sorry for such a late post. Here's the section from the docs: [Authentication overview from Quip API docs](https://quip.com/dev/automation/documentation/current#section/Overview) I work at AWS (where we work with Salesforce's Quip), and I had to have an admin create a secret ID etc. as a next step to get over this--I'll update this post when I see how it goes. However, according to the docs, it looks like you only need a personal token: [https://quip.com/dev/automation/documentation/current#section/Get-Access-to-Quip's-APIs](https://quip.com/dev/automation/documentation/current#section/Get-Acc